# My Python TeleBot Calculator doesn't work

Tags: python, bots, telegram, python-telegram-bot

This was the simplest code I've ever seen. My Python bot doesn't work.
The thing that's not working is, it doesn't start to do anything when /start command is sent to bot. Logicaly, it must start the `while` loop - It doesnt.
It even doesn't start with the function, `FirstNum()`. The idea was to use If - Else statement inside of loop.

Any suggestions?
I am a beginner in python coding, so don't judge me strict)

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def Main(message):
  a = 0
  b = 0
  c = 0
  while a + b + c > 0:
    if a == 0:
      FirstNum(message)
      break
      if a > 0 & b == 0:
        SecondNum(message)
        break
        if a > 0 & b > 0 & c == 0:
          ThirdNum(message)
          break
          if a + b + c > 0:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id,a + b + c.format(message.from_user, bot.get_me()))

def FirstNum(message):
  bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"Type your number > 0".format(message.from_user, bot.get_me()))
  a = message.text

def SecondNum(message):
  bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"Type your number > 0".format(message.from_user, bot.get_me()))
  b = message.text

def ThirdNum(message):
  bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"Type your number > 0".format(message.from_user, bot.get_me()))
  c = message.text
```

Comment: `a > 0 & b` is a [bitwise and](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators). I think you might mean `a > 0 && b`

Comment: Also, you haven't really said what "doesn't work". Is there an error, unexpect output? Without describing the current and expected behaviour nobody will be able to help much.

Comment: You haven't _called_ your functions, just defined them, so none of this code will run

Comment: But you were asked to expand on "doesn't work" and you didn't [edit] the question to add clarity to the actual problem

Comment: @roganjosh

I did edit my question, try to help me out please

Comment: @JimWright

I did edit my question, try to help me out please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a logical error in the while loop condition. So obviously the while loop won't run, because condition `0 + 0 + 0 > 0` will be false.

Try `a + b + c >= 0` condition in your while loop.